# Is GO allowed in SQL files passed to DbMigration.SqlFile?

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

The [DbMigration.SqlFile method](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn857435(v=vs.113).aspx) takes a `sqlFile` parameter which expects the path of a SQL file on disk, which is executed when the method is called.

**Question**

Is the SQL file provided to the DbMigration.SqlFile method's `sqlFile` parameter allowed to use the `GO` keyword to separate multiple batches of SQL statements?

Does whether or not `GO` is allowed vary based on the SQL Server version, the Entity Framework version, the .NET runtime version, or anything else?

**Full background**

My project is using Entity Framework version 6.

I have an Entity Framework migration class inheriting from [DbMigration](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.entity.migrations.dbmigration(v=vs.113).aspx) which just runs a SQL file on disk, e.g.:

```
public override void Up()
{
    this.SqlFile("/sql/StoredProcedures/MyMigrationFile.sql");
}
```

The contents of that file are like:

```
DROP PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[MyStoredProcedure]
  @MyParameter int
AS
  [Stored procedure SQL body here...]
```

In fact, my project has dozens of migration classes and SQL files like this, and they have worked fine since at least January 2016.

They still work fine when run on my team's Continuous Integration server (with Visual Studio 2015 and SQL Server 2014).

However, as of yesterday, when I tried running those migrations in my local environment (with Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server 2016), they fail with the error:

```
Incorrect syntax near 'GO'.
```

So, questions:

- Is `GO` supported in SQL files used with the DbMigration.SqlFile method, or not?
- What is the relevant difference between my local development PC and my team's CI server that's resulting in the migrations failing locally, but working fine in CI?

Comment: `GO` is not a T-SQL command, it's the batch separator for `sqlcmd` and scripts executed in SSMS. In any other context, `GO` will not work. Specifically, when the script is passed as-is to SQL Server as a batch, `GO` will not work. It sounds like that's exactly what's happening with your setup -- for what reason I couldn't tell. Check for something funky like CR/LF mismatches or invisible characters that could trip up code that tries to separate things by `GO`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem described in the original post above would occur when running unit tests, as the project is configured to use Entity Framework migrations to create and reconstruct the test database if it is missing, and to bring it up to the latest migration, before running any test methods.

The problem was that the test project in Visual Studio (i.e. a separate Visual Studio .csproj where our test classes are located) was missing its reference to the Entity Framework nuget package. The reference had somehow gotten broken or corrupted.

A symptom of this was that Entity Framework didn't appear at all in the list of references for the test project when running `Get-Package` from the Package Manager Console window in Visual Studio.

**The solution was to fix the Entity Framework reference** for the test project in the Package Manager Console window by:

1. In the "Default project" dropdown, selected my test project;
2. Ran: `Install-Package EntityFramework`

After doing that, the migrations ran successfully. The `Incorrect syntax near 'GO'` error no longer occurred.